How to get the string representation of a variable's name?
I'm working with PowerShell and I have a variable defined like this:
$name = "John"

I'm trying to find a way to get the string representation of the variable's name, which in this case would be name (without the $ symbol).
Is there a built-in method or a reliable technique to achieve this in PowerShell? I'm looking for a solution that would work for any variable, not just this specific example.

Can you explain the context? Why do you need this? If referencing a variable dynamically see this answer for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78727803/is-it-possible-to-reference-a-psobject-hashtable-name-via-a-variable/78727820#78727820

Assuming you have a piece of source code like described, you can use the [System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser]::ParseInput(...) method to parse it, at which point you can search the resulting syntax tree for variable expressions:
# define source code literal 
$sourceCode = '$name = "John"'

# parse source code to AST
$syntaxTree = [System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser]::ParseInput($sourceCode, [ref]$null, [ref]$null)

# search for all variable expressions on the left-hand side of `=`
$variableAssignmentTargets = $syntaxTree.FindAll({
  param($childAST)

  $childAST -is [System.Management.Automation.Language.VariableExpressionAst] -and 
  $childAST.Parent -is [System.Management.Automation.Language.AssignmentStatementAst] -and 
  $childAST -eq $childAST.Parent.Left
}, $true)

# process the found expressions
$variableAssignmentTargets |ForEach-Object {
  Write-Host "Found variable with path '$($_.VariablePath)' on line $($_.Extent.StartLineNumber), position $($_.Extent.StartColumnNumber)"
}

Which in this case would yield the message:
Found variable with path 'name' on line 1, position 1

The use of AST.FindAll() means you can find all such variable assignments in a complex piece of code:
$sourceCode = @'
$a = 123
$b = $a + ($c = 2)
'@

# ...

For which we can expect the output:
Found variable with path 'a' on line 1, position 1
Found variable with path 'b' on line 2, position 1
Found variable with path 'c' on line 2, position 12


Here is a simple short code:
Get-Variable | where 'Value' -Like $name | select -Expand 'Name'
I intentionally used -Like instead of -EQ, because -EQ also returns the automatic variables $? and $true, because their values are 'true'.
However, this can be a bug if your variable contains a 'wild character' like $name = "John*", as it will also return variables like 'johnn' and 'johnm'. So for a robust solution, you can use this:
Get-Variable | where { $name -eq $_.Value } | select -Expand 'Name'
Or:
(Get-Variable).Where({ $name -eq $_.Value }).Name

You should use -eq in both cases, but note that this is not an unambiguous solution, as multiple variables may contain the same value.

@mklement0 Test it and you will see why -eq is not good in this case. where 'Value' -eq $name also returns the automatic variables $? and $true because their values are 'true'. To keep the code short, it's better to use -like here. For the same reson I used in the second case $name -eq $_.Value and not $_.Value -eq $name. I have done a lot of troubleshooting until I found the correct short syntax.

@Someone: A simple test showing why -like isn't appropriate here: $a = 'foo'; $b = 'food'; $name = 'f*'; Get-Variable | where Value -Like $name. The larger point, however, is that your solution attempt is inherently ambiguous, whether or not you use -eq or -like: it cannot reliably identify the variable of interest.

@mklement0 OK, this will only happen if you have a 'wild character' in your variable. This it's not the case here, and is not common, in this case one can use my second code or Get-Variable | where { $name -eq $_.Value } | select -Expand 'Name'.

@Someone: The larger point stands: your solution inherently cannot unambiguously identify a single variable of origin; at the very least, this limitation should be a prominent part of your answer. Also, on a general note - irrespective of the specifics of the case at hand: If you arrived at a non-obvious solution, you should explain how you arrived at it as part of your answer, so that future readers don't have to guess.

Ah, I didn't see that comment. I'd bet mklement0 already has a post on the why that occurs, I'll search for it now to find the answer—life long learner here!

@mklement0 In my taste, I prefer short code, but I will update my answer to address your concern.

I just discovered if you end a variable with a semicolon, that issue when you set the variable explicitly and then run gettype() seeing array then string or even getting the ?, $ or true values in output is not an issue. So $name = "john"; rather than this $name = "john". I'll search for more of mklement0 awesome answers to find that tomorrow. I just found at least 3 comprehensive posts I learned more about PS. Mind blowing detail!

Thanks for updating, @Someone, but your solution still isn't a robust one, for the reasons stated (multiple variables can contain the same value).

@BitcoinMurderousManiac, thanks for the nice feedback; the reason that something like $true -eq 'any nonempty string' is $true is that the RHS ([string]) is coerced to the type of the LHS ([bool]), and coercing any nonempty string to [bool] yields $true. With simplified syntax, you don't get to control the order of the operands, so the regular, script block-based syntax must be used.
